# Vtiger Activity module to be added to custom Module

Tags: php, crm, vtiger, vtigercrm

http://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/extensions/examples/entity-module.html

using documentation given on the above link, I created a custom module named as Leaves. Now, next task was to add activity module to the Leaves module. I used following code do accomplish the same.

```
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php');
$moduleInstance = Vtiger_Module::getInstance('Leaves');
$accountsModule = Vtiger_Module::getInstance('Calendar');
$relationLabel  = 'Activities';
$moduleInstance->setRelatedList(
      $accountsModule, $relationLabel, Array('ADD','SELECT'), 'get_activities'
);
```

Now, in module/Leaves/Leaves.php i copied get_activities function from Accounts.php module of Accounts module. it should have worked now but it did not.

I added a single leave and opened it's detail view. I became happy by seeing Activities Label there. I clicked on it and added 2 events for particular single leave. Ideally, All events i.e 2 events that i recently added must be listed there but there was no event.

I checked codes and found out that a relation is being stored in 'vtiger_seactivityrel' table with activityid and single leave id(crmid). But when i add event from Leaves module. Activity is created but relation is not stored in 'vtiger_seactivityrel'. I made relation manually by adding activityid and crmid then it started showing events.

Hence, the question that is being raised here why 'vtiger_seactivityrel' table is not populated.

Please somebody help me if you have solution.[I have attached Image of one such leave which is showing blank even after adding event.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDo20.png)

Comment: Check the activity status. If it is Completed, Deferred it will not shown under related list. If status if different please share your logs so i can check and provide you solution.

Comment: I found the solution  man, I posted the answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of research i found out that i needed to update vtiger_ws_referencetype table for making the relation. Here is the query for the same. In my case custommodulename will be replaced by Leaves.

```
insert into vtiger_ws_referencetype(fieldtypeid,type) values (34,'custommodulename');
```